# Прямая линия на гистограмме, среднее значение в день по месяцу с обходом фильтрации по календарю

Tags: график, powerbi, powerquery, dax

Есть таблицы `amocrm_visits` и `date_table`

`amocrm_visits` выглядит примерно так:

| id | created_at | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12.06.2023 | 1200 |
| 2 | 12.06.2023 | 3000 |
| 3 | 13.06.2023 | 4200 |
| 4 | 13.06.2023 | 2400 |

`date_table` просто таблица с единственным столбцом `date`

У меня есть мера "Выручка", которая считается так:

```
Выручка = SUM(amocrm_visits[price])
```

И есть график, который я строю по дням (`date_table[date].[День]`), в котором отображается динамика выручки по дням

[image: График]

Мне нужно как-то посчитать среднюю выручку по дням в месяце так, чтобы она отображалась как прямая линия, проходящая сквозь эти столбики. Я пробовал считать так:

```
AVERAGE(amocrm_visits[amocrm_partners leads.price])
```

Но логично, что это не прокатило, так как она считает в контексте дня среднее значение и на графике просто повторяет столбцы

Тогда, я попробовал исключить дату, используя ALL, это действительно сработало и отобразило мне прямую линию, но не так, как надо, так как посчиталось среднее значение вообще по всей таблице, а мне нужно чтобы оно было средним за выбранный месяц:

```
CALCULATE(AVERAGE(amocrm_visits[amocrm_partners leads.price]), ALL(date_table))
```

Буду благодарен за помощь, весь день с этим вожусь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге решение я нашел.

Сделал вот такую меру:

```
Средняя выручка = DIVIDE([Выручка], DATEDIFF(STARTOFMONTH(DATE_TABLE[Дата]), TODAY(), DAY), 0)
```

Далее в графике перешел в пункт меню "Добавить дальнейший анализ в визуальный элемент" (лупа), и там добавил линию константы по этой мере

### [image: Как это выглядит в PowerBI]